# MySQL: create stored procedure and call it immediately

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I need to create a stored procedure then immediately call it, all within the same .sql file. The procedure is simple enough and just calculates the difference between income and outgoings.
The trouble is, when I call the procedure [I get this error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGecX.png)

the procedure is as follows:

```
DELIMITER $$            
    CREATE PROCEDURE crs.CurrentFinanceReport()
    BEGIN   
        DECLARE  income DECIMAL(6,2) default 0; 
        DECLARE  outgoings DECIMAL(6,2) default 0; 
        SET income = (SELECT SUM(invoice.TotalPrice) FROM crs.invoice INNER JOIN crs.orders ON orders.CustomerEmail = invoice.CustomerEmail WHERE orders.OrderStatus != "Recieved");
        SET outgoings =(SELECT SUM(OrderCost) FROM crs.stockOrder WHERE DateTimeRecieved = 0);
        SELECT (income - outgoings);
    END $$
    DELIMITER ;
```

And I am calling it with this:

```
CALL crs.CurrentFinanceReport();
```

If it helps at all, I have found that if the procedure is empty (nothing between BEGIN and END) it can call it without an error, but as soon as I add even a simple SELECT * it causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

`SET FORIEGN_KEY_CHECKS=ON` is a query generated by phpmyadmin and not your code. Use a mysql client and you probably won't encounter this error (or any others due to phpmyadmin "cleverness").